# Generating all possible 2x2 matrices with unique elements from 1 to 4

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, permutation

If I have a set `A={1,2,3,4}`, how do I generate all `2x2` matrices with different elements chosen from `A`?

It will be `4!=24` matrices like `{{1,2},{3,4}}`,  `{{1,2},{4,3}}` and `{{1,3},{2,4}}` ...

Comment: What about: Partition[#, 2] & /@ Permutations[{1, 2, 3, 4}]

Comment: `ArrayReshape[#, {2, 2}] & /@ Permutations[{1, 2, 3, 4}]`

Comment: Why is everyone posting solutions in the comments?

Answer (score 6):

Annotating my comment.
The expression `Permutations[{1, 2, 3, 4}]` generates all 24 permutations of the list {1,2,3,4}. For example, the list {3,1,4,2} is one of those.

In order to construct a 2x2 matrix from {3,1,4,2} one needs to partition the list into a matrix. This can be done by `Partition[{3,1,4,2},2]`. So why the funny `Partition[#, 2] & /@ Permutations[{1, 2, 3, 4}]`?

Well, the `Permutations[{1, 2, 3, 4}]` returns a List-of- List of all permutations; also called a nested list. A nested list has a double set of {{ }}, such as {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 4, 3}, ..., {4, 3, 2, 1}}. And each of the sublists has to be partitioned.

The syntax for `/@` is a Map, which maps the `Partition[#, 2] &` onto each of the sublists to create a  2x2 matrix. The `#` and `&` are essential parts of the Mathematica syntax.

So we end up with a double nested list {{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, {{1, 2}, {4, 3}}, ..., , {{4, 3}, {2, 1}}}. I hope this helps.

Comment: Or directly (without `Map`): `ArrayReshape[Permutations[{1, 2, 3, 4}], {24, 2, 2}]`

Answer (score 3):

Using integer manipulations only:

```
(res = Map[IntegerDigits, 
     QuotientRemainder[#, 
        100] &@(FromDigits /@ (Select[ContainsExactly[{1, 2, 3, 4}]]
          [IntegerDigits /@ Range[1234, 4321]]))
     , {2}]) // MatrixForm /@ # & // Multicolumn[#, 4] &
```

[image]

---

OR

```
(res2 = Select[ContainsExactly[{1, 2, 3, 4}]][
      Tuples[{1, 2, 3, 4}, 4]] /. {a_, b_, c_, 
       d_} -> {{a, b}, {c, d}}) // MatrixForm /@ # & // 
 Multicolumn[#, 4] &
```

---